# Printing the days of the month using the date error?

Tags: java, string, do-while

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lab42{

    public static void switchExample(){

        String str1;
        int s1, result;

        do {
            str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date: ");
            s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
            result = s1 % 7;

            switch (result){

                case 1:
                    System.out.printf("• %d falls on a Monday", s1); break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Tuesday", s1); break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Wednesday", s1); break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Thursday", s1); break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Friday", s1); break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Saturday", s1); break;

                default:
                    System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Sunday", s1); break;

            }
        } while(s1 <= 31 && str1.compareTo("quit") != 0);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        switchExample();
    }
}

output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "quit"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
    at Lab42.switchExample(Lab42.java:12)
    at Lab42.main(Lab42.java:44)
```

I want to take in the user's input between the number 1-31 and print the day it falls on, (assuming 1st is on a Monday), I want the loop to continue until the number is greater than 31 or the user's types quit. Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you!
(I'm new to StackOverflow, if the question is not according to the pattern please forgive me)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `quit` can not be converted into an integer; therefore, you need to first check the value of the input and break the loop if it is `quit`. If the input is not `quit`, check if it can be parsed into an `int` and loopback if the input is not parseable to an integer.

Do it as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1;
        int s1 = 0, result;
        boolean valid;
        do {
            do {
                valid = true;
                str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the date: ");
                if (str1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    s1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
                    if (s1 > 31) {
                        break;
                    }

                    result = s1 % 7;

                    switch (result) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.printf("• %d falls on a Monday", s1);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Tuesday", s1);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Wednesday", s1);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Thursday", s1);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Friday", s1);
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Saturday", s1);
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.printf("\n• %d falls on a Sunday", s1);
                        break;
                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong input. Try again.");
                    valid = false;
                }
            } while (!valid);
        } while (!str1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But, what if I want to use a do-while statement?

Comment: @SashrikR - I've updated the code to do it using `do-while`. Feel free to comment in case of any issue/doubt.